# Every time when I run the jmx file in Non-GUI mode the total transaction count very in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, query-performance, jmeter-4.0

I am new in Jmeter performance testing. My requirement is to run the jmx file in Non-GUI mode for a specific duration in different scenarios and collect the Aggregate report results .But every time I get the different total transaction count. My question is "Is it possible to make total transaction count as constant in every scenario. ".Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

By default JMeter sends requests **as fast as it can** so given your scenario the total number of transactions will vary **if response time varies**. I.e. if server response time is lower - you will have higher number of transactions and vice versa.

There are 2 ways to configure JMeter to send predefined number of requests:

1. Set fixed number of iterations under [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
2. Or limit number of executions via [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) in **Total Executions** mode. In this case all samplers in the Throughput Controller's [Scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) will be executed as many times as you specify in the "Total Executions" input field.